# Object doesn't support property or method 'slimtable' [IE, HTML, JavaScript, Jquery. ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm getting the below errir while using a Jquery function in IE.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'slimtable'

I've added the link to jquery file as well.

```
$(function() {
$("#autable").slimtable();
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you include the slimtable script?

Comment: Yeah, I've added that already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced the plugin in your code?

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='js/slimtable.min.js'></script>

Comment: My bad. The plugin comes with wrong instruction.The plugin comes with wrong instruction. The error is gone for now.But I'm still unable to see the pagination feature.

Comment: Btw, I'm trying to apply pagination on a table which is generated from an MDB using SQL on OLEDB. Is that gonna work?